# Stable_sort, как отсортировать только часть

Tags: c++

Третий день уже мучаюсь, не могу сообразить, подскажите пожалуйста, как отсортировать вот к примеру такие данные в массиве типа string следующим образом:

005

01

002

67

45

89

Мне нужно отсортировать данные только начинаюшиеся с нуля, с этим проблем нет:

```
Stable_sort(massiv.begin(), massiv.end(), [] (auto a, auto    b)
{
If((int)b[0][0]) == 48 && (int)a[0][0] == 48) //если первый элемент элемента b и a равно "0", то
{
return ((int)a[0][1]) < (int)b[0][1])); // отсортировать по второму элементу
}
else
{}
```

проблема возникает, как оставить абсолютно такой же порядок данных не начинаюшихся с нуля ?

Comment: у вас 002 > 01 > 005. как это понять?

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, это массив до сортировки, после должно быть вот так:002

005

01

67

45

89          отсортировать значения начинаюшиеся с нуля проблемы нет, я не знаю, как оставить остальные значения в том же порядке.

Comment: @Optimus1<  А вариант сначала разделить на два массива, потом отсортировать тот, что с нулями, и снова объединить - не подойдет?

Comment: Юрий Козлов, в совершенно безвыходной ситуации я бы так сделал, но тут все таки хотелось бы понять stable_sort просто позволяет вообще так сделать, вме таки делать на два мамсива, потом один сортировать, потом опять копировать в единый, как то не рацинально все таки наверное ?

Comment: @Optimus1, вот вы уже третий раз говорите о массиве, но не указываете для каких типов этот массив. Это массив С_строк или массив  чего?...

Comment: @Optimus1, Не спорю, не рационально :) Просто это сработает. Но наверное можно найти более эффективное решение.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, прошу извинить, массив string.

Comment: добавьте это в вопрос

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    vector<string> v = { "005", "01", "002", "67", "45", "89" };

    // делим массив на 2 группы, 1 - начинается с нуля, 2 - всё остальное
    auto it = stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const auto &x) { return x[0] == '0'; });

    // сортируем первую группу
    sort(v.begin(), it);

    for (auto &x : v) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: результат как у меня  можете получить, если вторую половину тоже отсортируете

Comment: @ARHovsepyan значит у вас ошибка, потому что значения, не начинающиеся с нуля, нужно оставить в том же порядке, в котором они были

Comment: вот поэтому я и написал, что был невнимателен, из за этого подумал, что ошибаетесь именно вы

Answer (score 0):

```
stable_sort(massiv.begin(), massiv.end(), [](auto a, auto b)
    { return (a[0] == '0') ? a < b : a == b; });
```

Comment: Юрий Козлов, Вы меня натолкнули на мысль :) почти так и сделал, только за место разделения на два массива просто указал функции stable_sort через и ераторы какой диапазон ей нужно сортировать, все оказалось просто:    

        Stable_sort(massiv.begin(), massiv.begin()+3, [] (auto a, auto b)
    {
    Return ((int)a[0][1]) < (int)b[0][1])); // отсортировать по второму элементу
    });

Comment: вообше то я не Юрий Козлов, а ваш вариант не подойдет

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, как же не подойдет, если он работает :)

Comment: любой код будет работать. Вопрос в том, что код работал не для частного случая, а всегда(был переносим). Если  элементы, начинающие  с нуля будут расбросаны по всему массиву,  что тогда? В конкретном вашем примере все такие элементы расположены в начале, поэтому вами придуманный вариант работает, но это лишь для частного случая. Плюс, функция не обязана знать сколько таких элементов существуют, он должна выполнить для произвольного количества

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, для случая когда все элементы массива предварительно не упорядочены, да так работать не будет.

Comment: и если вам неизвестно количество таких элементов, ваш вариант вообше не годится. Тогда предварительно еще нужно  определить это количество, удостовериться, что все расположены в начале, а потом сортировать (кстати, в другом ответе так и сделано, только с той разницей, что stable_partition выполняет функцию расположения таких элементов вперед)  .  Лучше просто написать код, который по любому выдаст желаемый результат, не зная ничего о количествах и о порядке.

Comment: AR Hovsepyan, а что будет работать быстрее? Предварительно отсортировать данные, посчитать кол-во нужных элементов и потом указав только нужный д апазон для сортировки - отсортировать или через stable_partition ?

Comment: конечно быстрее сортировать один раз(как я показал), чем  сортировать по предикату, потом сортировать еще и часть